# What's the difference between the following "either questions"?

Tags: differences

What is the best way to state this?

1. Either people should speak up about what bothers them, or just learn to live with other people's habits.
2. People should either speak up about what bothers them or just learn to live with other people's habits.

Could you tell me what the difference is?

Comment: Sentence 1 sets up a false parallel: Either (people should...) or (just learn...) They are not parallel. Could correct to: Either (people should...) or (**they should** just learn...)

Comment: @YosefBaskin - But you could parse it as: Either people should (speak up …) or (just learn …)

Comment: They are statements, not questions.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence 'either' is qualifing 'people'.

In the second sentence 'either' is qualifying what they should do.

That observation is not *just* so, because 'either' would not usually be applied to 'people' but to, say 'person'. Still I prefer the second sentence, modified to be

> People should either speak up about what bothers them or just learn to live with others' habits.

This avoids the repetition of 'people'.

Comment: No; 'Either A should X or Y' is just a variant of 'A should either X or Y'. The first should be avoided with say 'Either sheep should ...' where ambiguity arises.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so in answer to OP's question, neither is 'best'? Except where one is better.

Comment: The first variant is probably more informal in register, and the initial 'either' probably adds punch. But the garden path possibility is the major control factor. 'Either sheep can be treated for ....'